# git: how to force pull a branch if there are conflicts (becase someone force pushed)

Tags: git

I need to checkout and pull our prod branch.  I checked it out some time ago, and havent changed anything.

However people have force-pushed changes to prod branch, causing thousands of conflicts with my local copy when I try to pull.

If I try to delete the prod branch, I get:

```
% git branch -d prod
error: Cannot delete branch 'prod'
```

If I try to switch away from the prod branch, I can't:

```
% git checkout main
ui.front/src/components/Navigation/Navigation.tsx: needs merge
error: you need to resolve your current index first
```

Any suggestions?

Is there some sort of force checkout or force pull?  checkout -f doesnt help.

May be something like this would work, but I'm too scared to it unless someone can confirm it won't break anything and its the right thing to do:

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/prod
```

Comment: Do you care about the local commits on that branch?

Comment: _"confirm it won't break anything"_ - we cannot confirm that, but I would think that is what you need to do

Comment: I have no commits or modifications to prod - I checked it out once, and that was it.

Comment: Yes, that's the right command if all you need is to catch up your local branch to the remote's copy.

Comment: Then I would agree that `git fetch`, `git reset --hard origin/prod` would be the best course of action. Arguably, the other devs should not be force-pushing to a branch which is shared.

Answer (score 1):

1. Cleanup your current prod branch by either stashing, recommended (`git stash`) or if you don't care about the changes (`git reset --hard`)
2. `git branch -m prod_backup` # to rename your current prod banch to prod_backup (just in case)
3. `git fetch`
4. `git checkout prod` you should now have the changes which your colleagues pushed

Comment: Ok, I tried this option, but it doesnt work (as expected).  first I did "git reset --hard" to clear the millions of spurious conflicts (I havent changed anyting). Then I did git status, but it says your banch has diverged and there are untracked files (not from me), as well as it saying "you hacev 20 an 264 different commits.  If I try to pull, I get the same problem as before - millions of conflicts.

Comment: What's the result and what's the expectation? Also what does `git status` say?

Comment: maybe the problem is I need to do git reset --hard origin/prod instead of just git reset --hard? I dont know if there is a difference.

Comment: it should be easier to just delete the branch and start again, but this doesnt work either.

Comment: I didn't mention any pull in my answer, are you sure you're following the steps above?
Please post the result of `git status` after you run`git reset --hard`.

Does running `git clean -fd` after step 1 above help to get rid of the untracked files? If you're sure you don't need them?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to delete the offending branch, but I can confirm that the following worked:

```
git reset --hard origin/prod
git pull
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply delete locally prod and then re-download it.